# How to get securesocial library for Play Framwork Play 2.3.8?

Tags: scala, playframework, securesocial

There is link http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html. But It is not valid. Got error:-

```
 build.sbt:15: error: object Project is not a member of package play
 val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion,        
 appDependencies).settings(
              ^
 sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
 at sbt.compiler.Eval.checkError(Eval.scala:343)
 at sbt.compiler.Eval.compileAndLoad(Eval.scala:165)
```

There is example in github https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/3.0-M1

Can't build it. Error:-

```
  securesocial/samples/scala/demo/scalaDemo.sbt:1: error: not found:      
 object PlayKeys
 import PlayKeys._
        ^ 
 [error] Type error in expression
 Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Is there any working example to follow? So how to get it?

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned wrong version of play. I'm using Play 2.3.